# How to refresh div without refreshing whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a PHP file ***particular.php*** which have menu to serve sub pages. Once I click on a menu it loads page which I asked for without refreshing the main page i.e particular.php. Once the sub-page is loaded I create a SESSION which will store current page.

Following are codes I tried and seems no refreshing menu div.

```
echo '<footer id="ajaxmenu">';
echo '<ul>'
      if ( $_SESSION["ajax_show"] == 'result') {
           echo "<li style='text-decoration: underline;'>";
       } else {
              echo '<li>';
       }
       echo "<a href='#' onclick=\"result(); return false;\">Academic</a></li>";

 echo '</ul>';
 echo '</footer>';
}
```

JQuery ajax.

```
function result(year) {

    var year = year.value;
    $.ajax ({
           type: "POST",
            url: "result.php",
            data: { year: year},
            success: function(data),
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
    });    
    $("#ajaxmenu").load("#ajaxmenu");
    return false;
 }
```

In Nutsheell, When I click on menu, I want ***#ajaxmenu*** to be refresh without loading whole page.

Answer (score 1):

In your `AJAX success` replace `$("#result").html(data);` with `$("#ajaxmenu").html(data)`. As for now it seems like you are loading your data response in the wrong container - nothing of `id="response"` in your code.

Also, it might lead to nesting `<footer>` tags inside each other, so you should bear that in mind as you prepare the `HTML`.